# Handling NullPointerException when reading from file using Source.fromResource

Tags: scala

I get a strange behavior of `Source.fromResource()` method when reading from non-existing file. As far as I understand, it is supposed to return `null` so I wrap it into `Option`. But when matching it, it is recognized as `Some` and I get `NullPointerException`.

**ReadFromFileExample.scala:**

```
object ReadFromFileExample extends App {

  import scala.io.Source

  val sourceOpt = Option(Source.fromResource("non_existing_file.txt"))

  assert (sourceOpt.isDefined) // but it should return false

  sourceOpt match {
    case Some(source) => source.getLines()
    case None => throw new RuntimeException("Error reading from file")
  }

}
```

How to explain this behavior?

**UPD**

I was wrong. It should return non `null` value of type `BufferedSource`. But I suspect it can return value `null` of type `BufferedLineIterator`. I can't understand how does it return `NullPointerException` instead of `BufferedLineIterator`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, after pondering I concluded that it's better to use `Try` instead of `Option`, because it catches any exceptions

**Solution:**

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object ReadFromFileExample extends App {

  import scala.io.Source

  Try(Source.fromResource("non_existing_file.txt").getLines()) match {
    case Success(lines) => // handling lines
    case Failure(e) => println(s"An error has occured, cause: $e")
  }
}
```

**Update**

I've figured out how do I get `NullPointerException` when calling `getLines()`.

When method `fromResource` is called, there is a method `classLoader.getResourceAsStream()` which is called underneath. It returns `InputStream` which is `null` if file doesn't exist.

According the stacktrace below, this `InputStream` is passed until `Reader` constructor, where it serves as the object to synchronize on, namely `lock` field. If it is `null`, `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

**Reader.java**:

```
//...

protected Reader(Object lock) {
    if (lock == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    this.lock = lock;
}

//...
```

**Stacktrace** (from the snippet in my question):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:129)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.reader(BufferedSource.scala:22)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.bufferedReader(BufferedSource.scala:23)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.charReader$lzycompute(BufferedSource.scala:33)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.charReader(BufferedSource.scala:31)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.scala$io$BufferedSource$$decachedReader(BufferedSource.scala:60)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.<init>(BufferedSource.scala:65)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.getLines(BufferedSource.scala:84)
    at ReadFromFileExample$.delayedEndpoint$ReadFromFileExample$1(ReadFromFileExample.scala:12)
```

Answer (score -1):

replace  Option(Source.fromResource(...)) with  Try(Source.fromFile(...))

```
import scala.io.Source

val sourceTry = Try(Source.fromFile("non_existing_file.txt"))

sourceTry match {
  case Success(source) => source.getLines()
  case Failure(f) => println(f.getMessage)
}
```

Comment: It behaves the same. Even more I to need read from `resources` folder, so this wouldn't work if the file existed.